# Consumir servicio Rest api web POST desde c# enviando token

Tags: c#, api, webservice, rest

Hola a todos mi duda es cómo hacer lo siguiente: 
Tengo un servicio web que requiere de autorización Token para ser consumido, en las pruebas con POSTMAN ya me devuelve los datos que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora lo que quiero hacer es consumir o obtener ese JSON que me devuelve el servicio web para poder utilizarlo en una clase c#.
El código que tengo para eso es el siguiente:

```
private async void obtenerDataUsuarios()
    {
        string data = "";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44320///", 
                new StringContent( data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                urlValidacion = response.Headers.Location.ToString();
                string data2 = data;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Transaccion Fallida : " + response.ToString());
            }


    }
```

pero el depurador me devuelve el error 500 internal server error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servicio web no necesita ningún otro parametro más que el token para que devuelva esos datos

Comment: No es porque en tu URL de llamada tienes dos `/` extra al final? `https://localhost:44320///`

Comment: no, eso yo lo puse . ahí es donde van los nombres de los ws y los métodos pero los quité

Comment: debes agregar la ruta url tal como la tienes en postman

Comment: ya se, eso no es, porque en la misma clase también consumo el servicio web que obtiene el token, y ese si me lo regresa correctamente, sin embargo en este servicio web no

Comment: No uso el mismo método que el del token porque el token requiere de parametros de usuario y contraseña, pero este servicio web requiere de la autenticación por token

Comment: haz una llamada mas simple:      var client= new HttpClient(); client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
  var response = await client.PostAsync(url);

                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: y usa [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para analizar el llamado, de esta forma podras comparar con la que arma Postman

Comment: ya cambié el método a como tu lo pusiste y nada... error 500 internal server error

Comment: en que linea esta el error, puedes depurar el metodo del webapi asi sabras especificamente a que se debe.

Comment: En Postman tienes 10 Headers activos, uno de ellos debes necesitar en tu código para que funcione. Prueba quitando los headers en Postman y miras cuales son necesarios.

Answer (score 1):

En fin, si alguien llegó aquí teniendo el mismo problema les publico mi solución: usar la biblioteca RestSharp... Después de más de un día intentando encontrar una solución esta fue la única que funcionó.

```
        private string GeneraToken(TerminalData login)
    {
        string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(login);

        var client = new RestClient(*aca el URL*);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", inputJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Token = response.Content;

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error al obtener Token de Acceso: \n" + response.StatusCode, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return "";
        }

        Token = string.Format("Bearer{0}", Token).Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

        return Token;

    }
```